# Why I can not return enum with interface?

Tags: java, interface, enums, type-constraints

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11909783/1251549) answer. Everything is good, except that:

```
public <E extends Enum<E> & MyInterface> E getParametrizedEnum() {
    String someString = "..."
    return MyEnum.valueOf(someString); //compile error here
}
```

Intellij idea tells me "Required E, found com.mypackage.MyEnum".

Have to be cast like that:

```
public <E extends Enum<E> & MyInterface> E getParametrizedEnum() {
    String someString = "..."
    return (E) MyEnum.valueOf(someString); //compile error here
}
```

Is there a way to return parameterized enum with interface without casting?

Comment: Please show us `MyEnum`

Comment: It sounds like `MyEnum` doesn't implement `MyInterface`. But if it did, why not just use `MyEnum` as the return type? Or can you return different types of enums?

Comment: note that you're not getting any type guarantees for this method. Its return value can be assigned to literally any reference type without compile error: `java.awt.Point p = getParametrizedEnum();` see http://stackoverflow.com/q/338887/3385618

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the method does not return a `MyEnum`, it returns some class which extends both `Enum` and `MyInterface`. Even if `MyEnum` satisfies those contraints, there might be *other* enums which also implement `MyInterface`, and those are not necessarily assigment compatible with `MyEnum`.

Consider the following program:

```
interface MyInterface {} 
enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {
    A, B, C
}
enum YourEnum implements MyInterface {
    D, E, F
}

public class Foo
{
    public <E extends Enum<E> & MyInterface> E getParametrizedEnum() {
        String someString = "A";
        return (E) MyEnum.valueOf(someString); 
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        YourEnum b = foo.getParametrizedEnum(); // Ooops!
    }
}
```

It compiles perfectly fine but throws a `ClassCastException` at run-time!

But if you return a `MyEnum` anyway, why do you need generics? You can do:

```
public MyEnum getParametrizedEnum() {
    String someString = "..."
    return MyEnum.valueOf(someString); 
}
```

Comment: Why would they need to be assignment compatible? I can return an `ArrayList` from a method returning `Iterable`, even though there are other classes that implement `Iterable`. How is this situation different? What could go wrong if the compiler allowed this `return` statement?

Comment: But they are assignment compatible. `Iterable<String> a = new ArrayList<>()` is perfectly legal.

Comment: Ohh, I see now. The example you added is illuminating, thanks.

Comment: The main problem is to return 2 enums instead of one. That's why I need interface here to restrict enum numbers. It is possible to return an interface, but enum switching is lost in this case :(